# How to get Sentence ID by using corenlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using the stanford corenlp. I have a problem when I am using this package. How can I get the sentence ID of sentence.

ex: I bought a canon camera yesterday. It looked beautiful.
The output that I expected that I bought a canon..... sentence ID: 1
It looked beautiful. Sentence ID :2

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of what you do/what you tried?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to accomplish.